# retrive relation table in login request with laravel breeze

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8, laravel-breeze

Hello I want to include my relation table roles when I login. I used Laravel Breeze for authentication.

**Models/User.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    //old
    public function bookmarks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Post','post_bookmarks','user_id','post_id')->get();
    }    

    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Roles','roles','role_id','id');
    }
}
```

**AuthenticatedSessionController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the login view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming authentication request.
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**LoginRequest.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Lockout;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate the request's credentials.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

        if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
            RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => __('auth.failed'),
            ]);
        }

        RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
    }

    /**
     * Ensure the login request is not rate limited.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function ensureIsNotRateLimited()
    {
        if (! RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($this->throttleKey(), 5)) {
            return;
        }

        event(new Lockout($this));

        $seconds = RateLimiter::availableIn($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.throttle', [
                'seconds' => $seconds,
                'minutes' => ceil($seconds / 60),
            ]),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the rate limiting throttle key for the request.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function throttleKey()
    {
        return Str::lower($this->input('email')).'|'.$this->ip();
    }
}
```

I have used Laravel-breeze for the authentication. It's all working fine but I want to add Role name also when user gets login. As you can see I have also used relationship but I'm confused where can I write the code to get my relation table. This is my code, Can anyone please tell me how can I do?

For Ex.
login email: poojan@gmail.com
role_id = 1

in roles table
id: 1, role_name = "Wholseler"

So when I logged in currently I'm getting user data, But I want roles table data too.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So you want to attach role to user right ??

Comment: No, I already assign role to all user but when user login I want to retrieve Role name too.

Comment: So you need to redirect based on role right ??

Comment: All the code that you have provided is already built into framework. Can you tell me what you tried so far

Comment: When I logged in i want users pivot table data too, as you can see in example.

Comment: You can get relation data by doing this ```Auth::user()->roles```

Comment: I tried this but it says Undefined property: App\Models\User::$roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use attribute in your user model

```
protected $appends = ['role_name'];

public function getRoleNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->roles->first()->role_name ?? 'N/A';
}
```

using the above code you will get the role_name attribute in the user instance

if you want roles data into relations of user data try this in user model

```
protected $with = ['roles'];
```

Comment: Great, it's working. I used protected $with = ['roles']; all the data of roles table. Thank you so much. Can I add more tables in $with like $with = ['roles','products']; ?

Comment: yes definitely you can add more than one tables